# Using chrome to convert window.open to Chrome always on top panel

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a web app that is using javascript `window.open` command, my wish is to make these popups always on top.

Looking on the internet I saw recommendation to add `body.onBlur='self.focus'`.
This is not good for me because other windows cannot be accessed in this kind of approach.

What I thought is to write an extension that on pop-out will convert the `window.open`-opened pages to a chrome dialog.

1. The big question: This is even possible?
2. In the chrome dialog that I have tested the panels are always on to only if they are positioned in the top right of the window but if I am moving them to a different location the always on to function doesn't work

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/site-on-panel/pcjbpfaogjhnnnhdldamflaelejhbhag?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/picture-in-picture-viewer/efaagmolahogmekmnmkigonhfcdiemnl?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

Comment: When you say "I have an app" you mean a web app, not a Chrome App?

Comment: right a web app, updated the question

Comment: Then another question: are you writing this extension for yourself and not for general publication? I mean, is manually switching the panels flag okay for you?

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand the question.
I have a web app for my clients and I want to enable them the option for always on top my windows, the only way I can  think of is (if possible) open a panel instead of window,open

Comment: Then all of your clients will have to manually go to Chrome's experimental/unstable options and enable an unstable API.

Comment: Well, I don't like it but it can be done if the user wants an "Always on top option", I really cannot understand how this important option is ignored and not supported natively. My major concerns the pannel supports on top only when it placed in the right bottom of the screen? Is it possible to seamlessly convert a windows open to a pannel

Answer (score 2):

If you control the web app, you can replace window.open with a [Chrome App](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps). You can [send a message from the web app to the chrome app](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage), which can then use the [always on top app window option](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window) and [display it in a webview](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview).

Comment: This. A much better idea than trying to hijack the web app's code and use experimental API.